# Fat static library and framework saving?

Tags: ios, xcode

When using a fat (build for both simulator and device) static library or framework compares to device only static library or framework, I can't seem to see any difference of my app's size.

Is this because Xcode smart enough to only include the ARM architecture binary during archiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes. Xcode (rather, the compiler) only includes the ARM build because archived iOS builds are intended to ultimately be run on the target device. Because iDevices run on ARM, it is totally pointless to include an x86 binary in the package.